# OpenCPU cannot load Namespace 400 (Bad Request) Error in server mode

Tags: r, opencpu

I've written a OpenCPU app package and have successfully tested it in single server mode. The server is setup and it can find the app no problem.

But it's erroring out on some of the ocpu calls with the following (from Chrome JS console):

```
POST http://mydomain/ocpu/library/userengagementdashboard/R/metricsList 400 (Bad       Request) jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
OpenCPU error HTTP 400
package or namespace load failed for 'userengagementdashboard'

In call:
NULL
```

Didn't get these errors in the single user server mode.

If I check on http://`mydomain`/ocpu/library/userengagementdashboard/NAMESPACE I get:

```
export(aggregatePlot)
export(clusterFun)
export(facetPlot)
export(facetsList)
export(getDataAll)
export(getDataFacet)
export(getDataTime)
export(getDataTimeFacet)
export(mergeClusters)
export(metricsList)
export(timeFacetPlot)
export(timePlot)
import(RDruid)
import(ggplot2)
import(lubridate)
import(parallel)
import(plyr)
import(reshape)
```

Is there a problem with my imports maybe?

UPDATE:

Solved this thanks to Jeroen's suggestion that I perhaps didn't have all the dependencies.

First I looked at the dependencies under http://`mydomain`/ocpu/library/  and installed any missing packages to the correct library location.

Then some of the imports and dependencies of these dependent packages had not been installed so I installed their dependencies as well.  Problem solved!

Comment: Are all dependencies available? Try looking at `http://mydomain/ocpu/library/RDruid` etc. Also look at `/var/log/kern.log` if there are any `PERMISSION DENIED` errors.

Comment: Does it happen consistently or only for some calls? Might also be that your server runs out of memory?

Comment: I don't have the dependencies available in the ocpu library.  That would likely be the problem...

Comment: okay all dependencies should be available now adn there's nothing in the /var/log/kern.log.  But still getting the same error:  when I go to http://mydomain/ocpu/library/userengagementdashboard/R I get: package or namespace load failed for 'userengagementdashboard' In call:
NULL

Comment: I wonder if there's some other dependency that one of the imports has that's missing...

Comment: Can you post on the mailing list how this problem was caused? Because it should never happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package probably fails to load because some dependencies are not installed. This problem usually appears if the `NAMESPACE` file imports dependencies, which are not declared in the `DESCRIPTION` file. So if your `NAMESPACE` contains:

```
import(RDruid)
import(ggplot2)
import(lubridate)
import(parallel)
import(plyr)
import(reshape)
```

than your `DESCRIPTION` needs to contain a line:

```
Imports: Druid, ggplot2, lubridate, parallel, plyr, reshape
```

The R package manager looks at the `DESCRIPTION` to install dependencies when installing your package.